# Get operation data using javassist

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, javassist

I am trying to analyse byte code with javassist using simple class `MyData`:

```
class MyData {
    private Collection<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        // .....................    
    public void add(String str) {
        strings.add(str); // line number 35
    }
        // .....................    
}
```

Here is the code I am running against this class:

```
ClassFile cf = new ClassFile(new DataInputStream(TryJavassist.class.getResourceAsStream("MyData.class")));
MethodInfo minfo = cf.getMethod("add");  
CodeAttribute ca = minfo.getCodeAttribute();
for (CodeIterator ci = ca.iterator(); ci.hasNext();) {
    int index = ci.next();
    int op = ci.byteAt(index);

    System.out.println(op + "=" + Mnemonic.OPCODE[op] + ": " + minfo.getLineNumber(index));
}
```

It works and prints:

```
42=aload_0: 35
180=getfield: 35
43=aload_1: 35
185=invokeinterface: 35
87=pop: 35
177=return: 36
```

Line 35 invokes method `add()` of collection named `strings`. 
The code snippet I posted retrieves only `invokeinterface` and line 35. OK, I can know that it was class field (`getfield`).

I would like to know how to get the rest of information:

- the field name is `strings`
- the interface method being called is `add()`

Neither googling nor reading API doc have not given any positive result so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard work, needing an understanding of the JVM class format and instruction set.
Any answer can only give partial data. Especially with [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/). In the instruction typically one parameter is an index in the constant pool, where there is an object with an index to a name, and an index to a type. So be aware of what you are getting into.

If the class is compiled with debugging info, the private field names are accessible (ClassFile.getFields).

There is a nice Dump tool packed with javassist.

```
private void dumpMyDataClass() throws IOException, BadBytecode, Exception {
    ClassFile cf = new ClassFile(new DataInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyData.class")));

    // Dump fields:
    for (Object fieldInfoObj : cf.getFields()) {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = (FieldInfo) fieldInfoObj;
        System.out.printf("Field %s; %s%n", fieldInfo.getName(), fieldInfo.getDescriptor());
    }

    MethodInfo minfo = cf.getMethod("add");
    CodeAttribute ca = minfo.getCodeAttribute();
    for (CodeIterator ci = ca.iterator(); ci.hasNext();) {
        int address = ci.next();
        int op = ci.byteAt(address);

        String params = "";
        switch (op) {
            case Opcode.INVOKEINTERFACE:
                int a1 = ci.s16bitAt(address + 1);
                params += " " + cf.getConstPool().getInterfaceMethodrefName(a1);
                System.out.println("a1 = " + a1);
                break;
        }

        System.out.printf("Line %4d. Address %7d: %s%s%n", minfo.getLineNumber(address), address, Mnemonic.OPCODE[op], params);
    }

    // Command line tool of javassist:
    String pathToClass = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/classes/jeggen/test2/MyData.class";
    Dump.main(new String[] { pathToClass });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Although I did not really understand how do you know to call `ci.s16bitAt(address + 1);` but it works just fine. The only thing I still need is to get the field type name. I found method `getFieldrefType` into `ConstPool` but it still does not work for me. I will try to play with it but if you probably know what do I have to do to obtain this information could you please give me a tip?

Comment: You need a reference of the JVM instruction set for the operands: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html. I just showed s16bitAt for the first operand, and a part of the concerned const pool entry. In http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/index.html one sees getInterfaceMethodRefNameAndType and such.